# Unexpected space in outcome when combining len() to a string in python

Tags: python, whitespace

new programming student here!
I don't understand why this code returns "troy aikman has won 3" instead of "troy aikman has won3". There is no space after " has won" so I'm assuming it has to do with the ", len()" portion. I've switched the comma to "+" which gave me an error (as I thought it would). I haven't been able to find anything stating that len() automatically adds spaces so I've concluded that it has to be how the comma interacts with the len() function, but am confused as to how or why?

```
my_dict={
    "name":"troy aikman",
    "position":"qb",
    "team":"dalls cowboys",
    "age": 54,
    "weight": 220.,
    "superbowls":["XXVII","XXVIII","XXX"],
    "awards":{
    "super_bowl_mvp":"XXVII",
    "probowl":[1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996],
    "man_of_the_year":1997
    }
}
print(
    my_dict['name'] + " has won", len(my_dict['superbowls'])
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the `print` function prints each of the arguments specified, separated by a separator *sep*. The default value for *sep* is a space.

You are passing two arguments:

1: `my_dict['name'] + " has won"` (which evaluates to "troy aikman has won")

2: `len(my_dict['superbowls'])` (which evaluates to the number 3, whose string representation is "3")

So what prints is the first argument ("troy aikman has won"); the *sep* value (a space); and the second argument ("3"): "troy aikman has won 3"

Doc at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: Thank you so much! I sifted through so many articles and resources and knew it had to be a simple answer like this.

Comment: Great! If you find the answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

- use `f-string` is a better way than use `+` and `,` in string combination.

#### example

```
my_dict={
    "name":"troy aikman",
    "position":"qb",
    "team":"dalls cowboys",
    "age": 54,
    "weight": 220.,
    "superbowls":["XXVII","XXVIII","XXX"],
    "awards":{
    "super_bowl_mvp":"XXVII",
    "probowl":[1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996],
    "man_of_the_year":1997
    }
}

print(f"{my_dict['name']} has won{len(my_dict['superbowls'])}")
```

#### result

```
troy aikman has won3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using print statement printing two different values separated by commas. So by default there is a space

```
print(
    my_dict['name'] + " has won", len(my_dict['superbowls'])
)
```

If you want `troy aikman has won3` this then concatenate both values(both must in str form)

```
print(
    my_dict['name'] + " has won"+str(len(my_dict['superbowls'])
))
```